# Manipulating the String

Tags: java, string, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to manipulate the String.
Example:

```
RegistrationRequest.find({ 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode': 'RETPOSTREG',  $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode': 'COMPLETED' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode': 'ACT' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode': 'GSM' } ] } ] } ] },  {'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode': 1,_id:0}).sort({"serviceRequest.modifiedDate": 1})
```

I want to separate the above into 3 strings

which are like below:

```
 query = { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode': 'RETPOSTREG',  $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode': 'COMPLETED' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode': 'ACT' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode': 'GSM' } ] } ] } ] }

projection = {'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode': 1,_id:0}

sort = {"serviceRequest.modifiedDate": 1}
```

i am able to separate sort as below - sort may not be there always.

```
if(query.contains("sort"))
        {
            String sortParams = query.substring(query.lastIndexOf(".")+1, query.lastIndexOf(")")-1);
        }
```

got other value as

```
String parseQuery = query.substring(query.indexOf("(")+1, query.lastIndexOf(".")-2);
```

now the parseQuery has string:

```
 { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode': 'RETPOSTREG',  $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode': 'COMPLETED' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode': 'ACT' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode': 'GSM' } ] } ] } ] },  {'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode': 1,_id:0}
```

Now i need to separate the above as two strings, the string between last {} are projections in mongodb that i want as separate string say projection.

can any one help me on this.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: Adding the language tag will increase the chance that you get a helpful answer. Is this java?

Comment: yes, it is java. I want to run mongo queries, before running i need to separate the string as query parameters to one string, return parameters to one string and sort parameters to another string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to manipulate the string.
Below is the code :

```
String sortParams="";
String findParams = "";
String returnParams="";
//if sort is there then this keyword will be there
String sortStr = "sort";
//if return params exist then only the below substring will be there
String retStr="]},{";

//remove extra spaces in the query
        query = query.replaceAll(" ", "");

        if(query.contains(sortStr))
        {

             sortParams = query.substring(query.lastIndexOf(sortStr)+5, query.lastIndexOf(")"));

             query = query.substring(0, query.lastIndexOf(sortStr)-1);
        }

        if(query.contains(retStr))
        {
            returnParams =   query.substring(query.lastIndexOf(retStr)+3, query.length()-1);

            query = query.substring(0, query.lastIndexOf(retStr)+2)+")";
        }

         findParams = query.substring(query.indexOf("(")+1, query.length()-1);
```

eg:- 
Actually Query :

```
RegistrationRequest.find({ 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode': 'RETPOSTREG',  $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode': 'COMPLETED' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode': 'ACT' },  { $and: [ { 'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode': 'GSM' } ] } ] } ] },  {'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode': 1,_id:0}).sort({serviceRequest.modifiedDate})
```

after exeuction of if(query.contains(sortStr)) statement

```
sortparams : {'serviceRequest.modifiedDate':1}
Query after sort params removed :RegistrationRequest.find({'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode':'RETPOSTREG',$and:[{'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode':'COMPLETED'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode':'ACT'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode':'GSM'}]}]}]},{'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode':1,_id:0})
```

after exeuction of if(query.contains(retStr)) executed

```
returnParams :{'serviceRequest.customer.profileDetails.basicDetails.customerCode':1,_id:0}
Query after return params removed :RegistrationRequest.find({'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode':'RETPOSTREG',$and:[{'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode':'COMPLETED'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode':'ACT'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode':'GSM'}]}]}]})
```

after execution of last statement

```
findParams :{'serviceRequest.serviceRequestSubtype.masterCode':'RETPOSTREG',$and:[{'serviceRequest.serviceRequestStatus.masterCode':'COMPLETED'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.serviceStatus.masterCode':'ACT'},{$and:[{'serviceRequest.customer.services.service.0.serviceDetails.technology.masterCode':'GSM'}]}]}]}
```

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: this code is error prone and is hard to reason about